# Check if joined result set contains some value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database structure similar to this:

```
asset
+----+---------+
| id | user_id |
+----+---------+

user_favorite
+----------+---------+
| asset_id | user_id |
+----------+---------+
```

I am looking to create a query where I can return all assets belonging to a given user AND a boolean indicating whether or not it is a "favorite" for them.

I can do this, where a count() equalling zero would mean it's not a favorite (but it seemed hacky and inefficient):

```
select distinct(a.asset_id), 
    (select count(*) 
     from user_favorite f 
     where f.user_id = MY USER ID 
       and f.asset_id = a.asset_id) 
from asset a 
left join user_favorite u on a.asset_id=u.asset_id 
where a.user_id = MY USER ID;
```

I tried this (but it yielded multiple entries from assets when multiple users had favorited them:

```
select distinct (a.asset_id), 
    (u.user_id in (MY USER ID)) 
from asset a 
left join user_favorite u on a.asset_id=u.asset_id 
where a.user_id = MY USER ID;
```

I also tried this (but the IN condition wasn't respected):

```
select distinct(a.asset_id), 
    (u.user_id in (MY USER ID)) 
from asset a 
left join user_favorite u on a.asset_id=u.asset_id 
where a.user_id = MY USER ID group by u.user_id;
```

Is there some good way to do this query?

Comment: Yeah, I've just noticed that it seems like you might have simplified your schema for the question. Is the `Asset` table actually a `UserAsset` table? Otherwise why are you selecting DISTINCT, unless the column labelled `id` is actually not an id.

Comment: It's a simplified schema. Sorry. The asset.id doesn't really need to be DISTINCT, and it is the id that is referenced in user_favorite.user_id.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it, but I'm sure there are many acceptable ways:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.asset_id 
    ,CASE WHEN u.asset_id IS NULL 
          THEN 0 
          ELSE 1 
     END AS IsFavourite
FROM asset a
LEFT JOIN user_favourite u ON a.asset_id = u.asset_id 
                           AND a.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE a.userid = MY_USER_ID
```

`LEFT JOIN` favourites to assets, and if there is no favourite record present (`u.asset_id IS NULL`) then it is not a favourite, otherwise it is.

Comment: You refer to `a.asset_id` despite the column appearing to be called just `id`, so I've stuck with that since it's clearer.

Comment: The second join condition was the key. Thanks!

Comment: :P haha and I left that out to begin with, took me a few mins to notice, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps a little

```
select 
     assetid,
     case when isnull(fav.user_id,0) =1 Then 0 else 1 end
form
     asset a
     left outer join 
     user_favourite fav
     on a.user_id = fav.user_id
where
     fav.id = 'foobar'
GROUP BY assetid, fav.user_id
```